# Difference between JFormattedTextField and DocumentFilter?

Tags: java

I'm dealing with these two topics at the moment and i'm not sure which of them i should use because in my opinion i use both to determine what a person can enter into the program???

THX

Comment: `JFormattedTextField` primarily provides formatting for the input, attempting to ensure that the input meets the requirements of the specified format. From memory, `JFormattedTextField` uses a `DocumentFilter` internally as part of its operations. `DocumentFilter` provides a means of filtering input going to a `Document`, allowing you to prevent some all of the text reaching the `Document`.  It's much more direct but flexible

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem? That will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask